# Как отфильтровать массив по нескольким значениям?

Tags: javascript, фильтрация

Пытаюсь осилить мультифильтр. Есть переменная с товарами, у каждого товара есть свой id и набор свойств. Есть фильтр с массивом activeOptions, заполняется при переборе активных чекбоксов. Фильтрацию товаров провожу таким образом - делаю копию массива с товарами и удаляю из нее неподходящие товары. Проблема возникла на стадии с indexOf. Почему то удаляется меньше значений чем должно было, остаются товары которые по логике не подходят. Не могу понять почему это происходит да и вообще правильный ли я мвыбрал метод.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
let products = [
    {
      filterOptions: {
       Бренд: "NK", 
       Тип тормозного диска: " вентилируемый ", 
       Вес [кг]: " 6.29 ", 
       Число отверстий в диске колеса: " 5 отверстия ", 
       Диаметр [мм]: " 300"
      },
      id: 2
     },
   {
    filterOptions: {
      Бренд: "MEYLE", 
      Сторона установки: " задний мост ", 
      Наружный диаметр [мм]: " 300", 
      Высота [мм]: " 66 ", 
      Толщина тормозного диска (мм): " 20"
     }, 
    id: 3
];

    let filter = {
      activeOptions: {Бренд: "NK", Тип тормозного диска: " вентилируемый ",}
    }


    function filterProducts() {
        filter.activeOptions = []

        $(".filter input:checked").each(function (index, input) {
            let val = $(input).attr("value")
            let key = $(input.closest(".filter__item")).attr("data-filter")

            if (key in filter.activeOptions) {
                filter.activeOptions[key].push(val)
            } else {
                filter.activeOptions[key] = new Array()
                filter.activeOptions[key].push(val)
            }
        })

        $("table tr:has('.table-advance')").hide()

        let filteredProducts = products.map(val => val)

        for (let option in filter.activeOptions) {

            filteredProducts.forEach(product => {

                if (filter.activeOptions[option].indexOf(product.filterOptions[option]) === -1) {

                    const idx = filteredProducts.findIndex(el => el.id === product.id)

                    filteredProducts.splice(idx, 1)

                    console.log(product.filterOptions);
                    console.log(filter.activeOptions);
                }
            })
        }

        filteredProducts.forEach(product => {
            document.querySelector(`tr[data-id="${product.id}"]`).style.display = ""
        })
    }

    $(".filter").on("change", ".filter__checkbox", filterProducts)
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уберите РУССКИЕ наименования ключей в объектах. Это очень небезопасно.

Comment: они динамически генерируются по описанию товара

Comment: Что это меняет? У вас есть код, который автоматически генерирует русские названия свойств для объекта. Это небезопасно, это странно, это лишнее.

Comment: Это станет проблемой если код не уйдет дальше клиента?

Comment: Если сейчас все работает как есть, то не думаю. Проблемы всплывут при дальнейшем расширении проекта, если оно вообще будет. Также риск не уснуть, когда Ваш преемник будет материть Вас на чем свет стоит, переписывая класс продуктов ночами

Answer (score 0):

Разобрался
Нельзя было использовать slice вместе c foreEach.